# Goto Next Anchor Button

Tags: javascript, html, button, anchor

I have set up some anchors and a little menu up top. when I click a menu item, it will scroll to that anchor.

what I want to do is have a next arrow on the menu to determine the next anchor on my page and scroll to it onClick.

My anchors are #header, #box1 - #box5

I would like to do it with JavaScript if possible.
here is my page

[My Page](http://ahuge.ca/nick)

Answer (score 2):

There is an HTML collection called `document.anchors`. To go to the next anchor, get the current anchor name from the URL and look for it in `document.anchors`. If you find it, the next one will be the next index. If you're at the last index, set the anchor to the first. Otherwise, if there is no match, just set it to the first.

This allows you to use any scheme for naming anchors, they will be visited in the order they appear in the DOM.

e.g.

```
<head>
<!-- Hide script-dependent content -->
<style type="text/css">
.requiresScript-block, .requiresScript-inLine {
  display: none; 
}
div.spacer {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function goToNextAnchor() {
  var anchors = document.anchors;
  var loc = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
  var nextAnchorName;

  // Get name of the current anchor from the hash
  // if there is one
  var anchorName = window.location.hash.replace(/#/,'');

  // If there is an anchor name...
  if (anchorName) {

    // Find current element in anchor list, then
    // get next anchor name, or if at last anchor, set to first
    for (var i=0, iLen=anchors.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (anchors[i].name == anchorName) {
        nextAnchorName = anchors[++i % iLen].name;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // If there was no anchorName or no match,
  // set nextAnchorName to first anchor name
  if (!nextAnchorName) {
    nextAnchorName = anchors[0].name;
  }

  // Go to new URL
  window.location.href = loc + '#' + nextAnchorName;
}

// Display script-dependent content if javascript available
document.write(
  '\u003Cstyle type="text/css"\u003e' +
  '.requiresScript-block {display: block;}' +
  '.requiresScript-inLine {display: inline;}' +
  '\u003C/style\u003e'
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#header">Go to header</a>
    <li><a href="#box1">Go to box 1</a>
    <li><a href="#box2">Go to box 2</a>
    <li><a href="#box3">Go to box 3</a>
    <li><a href="#box4">Go to box 4</a>
    <li><a href="#box5">Go to box 5</a>
  </ol>

  <!-- Only shown if javascript available -->
  <button class="requiresScript-inLine" onclick="goToNextAnchor()">Next</button>

  <a name="header"></a><h1>Header</h1>
  <div class="spacer">content</div>
  <p><a name="box1"></a><p>Box 1</p>
  <div class="spacer">content</div>
  <p><a name="box2"></a><p>Box 2</p>
  <div class="spacer">content</div>
  <p><a name="box3"></a><p>Box 3 </p>
  <div class="spacer">content</div>
  <p><a name="box4"></a><p>Box 4</p>
  <div class="spacer">content</div>
  <p><a name="box5"></a><p>Box 5</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something using an onClick in your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToNext();return false;">===></a>
```

...and then the JavaScript:

```
var max = 5;

function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/box/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#box",""));
        (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#box" + String(newh+1); 
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "box1";        
    }
}
```

Change `max` the highest number you want to go (for `box1`, `box2`, etc...). Not sure if this will keep the animation, but you can take a look at an example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/xcWCK/show/light/). Just watch the address bar.