# button to jump to next anchor

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress-website with section scrolling enabled and added 2 buttons that should jump to the previous or the next page on the website and 2 buttons that should jump to the previous or next chapter on the website.

based on this post [Goto Next Anchor Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796876/goto-next-anchor-button) I added the script but the browser returns the length = 0 for anchors, document.getElementByTagName() returns an array that is to big
and document.getElementByName() didn't work too.

```
var anchordivs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-anchor][data-id]');
var anchors = anchordivs.length;
var loc = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
var nextAnchorName = 0;

var anchorName = window.location.hash.replace(/#/,'');


if (anchorName){

    for (var i=0, iLength=anchordivs.length; i<iLength; i++) {
        if (anchordivs[i].dataset.anchor == anchorName) {

            nextAnchorName = anchordivs[i+1 % iLength].dataset.anchor;
        break;
        }
}
}
if (!nextAnchorName){
   nextAnchorName=anchordivs[0].dataset.anchor;
}

window.location.href = loc + '#' + nextAnchorName;
}
```

On button click the site should scroll to the next section of the website.

EDIT: wordpress did create the anchors as data-anchors in the respective divs:
`<div ... data-anchor="c_home">`. Here is what still does not work. On clicking the button the site does not jump to the new anchor and manually entering a anchor in the adressline of the browser does not work either. The JS-Code is tested and works now.

Maybe the problem for the missing jump is that it is all on one page?

I got it working by changing the last codeline to the following:

```
location.href ='#' + nextAnchorName;
location.reload();
```

Now its reloading the site with each click, but it works. That is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");` and `nextAnchorName = anchors[i++ % iLen].name;`

```
function goToNextAnchor() {
  var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var loc = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
  var nextAnchorName;

  // Get name of the current anchor from the hash
  // if there is one
  var anchorName = window.location.hash.replace(/#/,'');

  // If there is an anchor name...
  if (anchorName) {

    // Find current element in anchor list, then
    // get next anchor name, or if at last anchor, set to first
    for (var i=0, iLen=anchors.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (anchors[i].name == anchorName) {
        nextAnchorName = anchors[i++ % iLen].name;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // If there was no anchorName or no match,
  // set nextAnchorName to first anchor name
  if (!nextAnchorName) {
    nextAnchorName = anchors[0].name;
  }

  // Go to new URL
  window.location.href = loc + '#' + nextAnchorName;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but when using the button nextAnchorName returns "undefined".

Comment: I see it on the website itself, when using the button: http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/#undefined Unfortunately neither firefox nor chromium want to show me the values of my variables

Comment: my anchors are hidden, i found them in the div-section: <div .... data-anchor "c_home">. Can I access this data-anchor?

Comment: @Zehke yes.if you can access to ```href``` tag,and use instead ```window.location.href = loc + '#' + nextAnchorName;```

Comment: the button is mostly working, the loop is working and the address-line is properly updated. The only thing that doesnt happen, on clicking the button the button doesnt scroll to the next div-data-anchor

Comment: ```window.location.href = loc + '#' + nextAnchorName;``` is work correctly?  ```loc + '/# '``` is propose to you.

Comment: Maybe the issue is, that it is all on one page?

Comment: I would like to send you a link to the website instead as soon as the server is online, if that is ok.