# div data-anchors not working without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a website created with wordpress with different chapters and one div represents one page. At the bottom I have a button with which you can go to the next div. The script is basically working, but the site does not jump to the div without reloading the page.
This question is related to this question: [button to jump to next anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194843/button-to-jump-to-next-anchor).

the anchors are stored as data-anchors in divs: `<div ... data-anchor="c-home">` and i want to jump from one div to the next with this script:

```
function goToNextSection(){

var anchordivs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-anchor][data-id]');
var anchors = anchordivs.length;
var loc = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
var nextAnchorName = 0;

var anchorName = window.location.hash.replace(/#/,'');


if (anchorName){

    for (var i=0, iLength=anchordivs.length; i<iLength; i++) {
        if (anchordivs[i].dataset.anchor == anchorName) {

            nextAnchorName = anchordivs[(i+1) % iLength].dataset.anchor;
        break;
        }
}

}
if (!nextAnchorName){
nextAnchorName=anchordivs[0].dataset.anchor;
}
document.location.hash ='#' + nextAnchorName;
document.location.reload();
```

Without the reload()-command the adress-line of the browser would be updated but the actual scrolling down would not work. If I scroll with the mouse the anchors are updated properly in the adress-line. However manually changing the anchor in the adress-line does not jump to the section too.

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixing with '#' when you're updating location.hash is unnecessary.

Change `document.location.hash ='#' + nextAnchorName;` to simply `document.location.hash = nextAnchorName;`

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nireno/1q0zahvb/20/).